# vpython and pyinstaller: "file separator seems to be c\"

Tags: pyinstaller, vpython, filenotfounderror

I have a python script that uses vpython. I used the following command to create the exe

pyinstaller --onefile  --debug=all --add-data "/users/userid/.conda/envs/math/Lib/site-packages/vpython/vpython_libraries/*;./vpython/vpython_libraries/" .\test6.py

EXE got created. When I run I get error(s)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI136922\vpython\vpython_librariesc\plotly.min.js'

As you can see it has added "c\" between vpython_libraries and "plotly.min.js" when it is looking for the file.

Are there any suggestions? Thank you.

tried different ways of copying the files. none were successful so far.

Comment: I know nothing about pyinstaller, but I'll point out that unless your VPython program imports Python modules other than random, you could go to webvpython.org, sign in and copy your program to the editor there, then click "Run this program" to see that it works and, if so, click "Share or export this program" to see the various ways you can make your program available without requiring the viewer to install any software.